# Why mockito returns error eve argument are identical?

Tags: testing, junit4, mockito, hamcrest

Take a look at this picture. what is going on with Mockito verifying Argument ?

I want to verify that view is invoked with the argument factory.

```
 @Test
  public void shouldInitializeTheDriverWithTheRequestFactory() {

    CVProxy proxy = context.create(CVProxy.class);

    workflow.initialize();

    verify(view).initializeWithRequestFactory(factory);

    verify(view).editWithEditor(proxy, context);

  }
```

However I got this error which is weird ?!

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
view.initializeWithRequestFactory(
    com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.InProcessRequestFactory@13c6a22
);
-> at CreatingNewCVWorkflowTest.shouldInitializeTheDriverWithTheRequestFactory(CreatingNewCVWorkflowTest.java:53)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
view.initializeWithRequestFactory(
    com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.InProcessRequestFactory@13c6a22
);
```

as you can the arguments are IDENTICAL. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that the factory instance has an incorrectly implemented equals method (so that the equals method reports that the object is not equal to itself)?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Neither it nor its superclasses--[`AbstractRequestFactory`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/impl/AbstractRequestFactory.java) and [`IdFactory`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/web/bindery/requestfactory/shared/impl/IdFactory.java)--implement `equals`.